# Printing 5 number on a play card at once

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help.
I’m  automating a task.
I would like to automatically select 5 numbers on the game card using my Excel program (created using VBA language).
I would place a symbol (chr 149) on the selected numbers using the printer.
Numbers are printed on the game card and I need to select them.

At the moment, I’m able to select and print only one number at a time.
So, I ask you how I can select 5 numbers printing for five times the character 149 on the same card at once.
Following the code I use to select only one number at once.

Thank you in advance

```
Sub PrintNumbers()

With ActiveSheet
    With .PageSetup
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.13)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.707)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.528)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
         End With
End With
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```

I tried using repeated cycles

Comment: This code prints a page, it does not care whether there's a number on it.

Comment: Hi Dominique, I have edited my question. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Sorry, but I fear you might need to show how your Excel page looks like (again by editing your question).

Comment: A screenshot is helpful to know your question.

Comment: link screenshot file Excel :                                                                                           https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ox9s7G7nzIQKSFne3e9qBn6w3adQUPgY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: link picture play card:                                                                                                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/155-gbADxPSSzR14D7Fr12Cjol4x3h25S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In cell A1 there is a little circle (chr 149). I need to place this little circle on five numbers on the play card. At the moment I''m able to place only one circle at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved using Shapes objects.
Using a cycle, I delete all shapes and after I create new Shapes using `AddShape` method. In this case I print a little circle on numbers 1,2,3

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim DistTop     As Long
    
    '''delete all shapes
    
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp
    DistTop = 8
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeFlowchartConnector, 46, DistTop, 7, 7.75). _
                                                                Select
            Selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset8
            
            DistTop = DistTop + 12
        Next i
        
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        
    End Sub
```